# HREF + TEXT with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I've the following HTML Page:

```
 </div><div id="page_content_list01" class="grid_12">
 <h2><strong class="floatleft">TEXT1</strong></h2><br>
    <table>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="no_width">

<p class="floatleft">Attachments:</p>
        </th>
        <td class="link_azure">   
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com">TEXT2</a><br/>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    </table><h2><strong class="floatleft">TEXT3</strong></h2><br>
    <table>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="no_width">

<p class="floatleft">Atachments:</p>
        </th>
        <td class="link_azure">   
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example2.com">TEXT4</a><br/>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    </table><h2><strong class="floatleft">TEXT5</strong></h2><br>
    <table>

<tbody>
    <tr>
```

Actually I'm doing:

```
 Elements rows = document.select("div#page_content_list01");
```

Now I to select "TEXT" and link. I wanna to make clickable link, so I'm using:

```
  for (Element eleme : rows) {
       Elements elements = eleme.select("a");
       for (Element elem : elementi) {
            String url = elem.attr("href");
            String title = elem.text();
       }
  }
```

and I'm getting:

```
 url = "http://www.example.com";
 title = "TEXT2";
```

and it's ok, but in this way I can't read "TEXT1" and "TEXT3".
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to work on the selecors. First, your primary selector

```
Elements rows = document.select("div#page_content_list01");
```

will return with a list of ONE element only, since you actually select the div, not the tables or table rows. I would instead do this to get all relevant info:

```
Elements tables = document.select("div#page_content_list01>table");
for (Element table : tables){
  Element h2 = table.previousElementSibling();
  String titleStr = h2.text();
  Element a = table.select("a").first();
  String linkStr = a.attr("href");
}
```

Note that the Text in the `h2` elements is on the same level as the table, not inside a common div. This is why I use the previous sibling notation. Also note that I wrote this out of my head and it is untested. You should get the idea though.